# How to Replace null with value when null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a join query, I want Replace a NULL value with a string if is null.
If it is not NULL, replace with a null string.

```
select distinct Code= R_Schedule.FoodId,Name= FoodName + ' = price ' +(CONVERT( varchar(50),R_Foods.FoodPrice) + ISNULL(str(R_Schedule.dayId ),' - public-'))    from R_Foods join R_Schedule on R_Foods.FoodId=R_Schedule.FoodId where R_Schedule.DayId=6 or DayId is null
```

please this this Image :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kv81f.png

Important section of my query is :

```
 ISNULL(str(R_Schedule.dayId ),' - public -'))
```

This section if it is null return 'public' else if it is not null return column's id.
I don't want return id if it is not null.

Comment: which database you are using ? coz its DB specific

Comment: `Case When Then` would work

Comment: @JenishRabadiya Can you post your answer .please

Comment: @JenishRabadiya I don't know how work with case .

Comment: @PsarTak can you please post your table schema?

Comment: @PsarTak sorry misunderstood your question. `I dont want return id if is not null` What do you want in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CASE WHEN`. When `dayId`  is null then it will return `- public-` Else it will concat with `''` Empty string
 which you can use the other value to set if you want.

```
select distinct 
   Code = R_Schedule.FoodId,
   Name = CASE WHEN R_Schedule.dayId IS NULL THEN  FoodName + ' = price ' +(CONVERT( varchar(50),R_Foods.FoodPrice)) + ' - public-'
              ELSE  FoodName + ' = price ' +(CONVERT( varchar(50),R_Foods.FoodPrice)) + 'othervalue' END
from 
   R_Foods join R_Schedule 
      on R_Foods.FoodId=R_Schedule.FoodId 
where 
     R_Schedule.DayId=6 
     or DayId is null
```